# PHP - inverse of dependency with templates?

Tags: php, templates

Usually I do `require lib.php` in templates, where I refer to the file with implemented functions:

**lib.php** :

```
function output(){
 echo "test";
}
```

and     **template.php**:

```
    head
    {?php
    require lib.php;
    output();
    ?>
    ...
```

Now I would like to have two different files `lib1.php` and `lib2.php` with two differenet implementations of `output()`.

From `lib1.php` `lib2.php` I would like to refer the template.php, and inject the apropriate implementation of `output.php`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [OOP functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)?

**Lib1.php**

```
class Lib1 {

   public function output()
   {
      return 'Library 1!';
   }

}
```

**Lib2.php**

```
class Lib2 {

   public function output()
   {
      return 'Library 2!';
   }

}
```

In your other PHP files:

```
$lib1 = new Lib1();
echo $lib1->output();

$lib2 = new Lib2();
echo $lib2->output();
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer, I did not want to use OOP, because I ould like to  keep my template in a separate file (template.php). This file has only little php and much html. So I do not want to wrap it by a huge echo. Is there a way to load `template.php` from class `Lib2` and replace all the `output` function calls in template.php by the appropriate implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It's time for OOP (object oriented programming). This is a perfect situation for a class with extensions. Otherwise a big question. [Look here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) if you're interested.